# Image resource as source for Image not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I defined a custom loading spinner UserControl in a WPF UserContol library.
It has one dependency property:

```
public string SpinnerSourcePath { get => _spinner.Source.ToString(); set => _spinner.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(value); }

public static readonly DependencyProperty SpinnerSourcePathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SpinnerSourcePath), typeof(string), typeof(Spinner));
```

where `_spinner` is the `Image`.
(I tried it directly with `ImageSource` class but no dice)

The xaml looks like this:

```
<Image x:Name="_spinner" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
    <SomeStyleToMakeItRotate.../>
</Image>
```

and I use it by defining it like:
`<c:Spinner SpinnerSourcePath="/Test;component/_Resources/loading.png"/>`
(The project name is `Test`, the `Spinner` control resides in a different project), nothing is displayed.

However, if I add the `Source` property directly in the `Spinner` definition:

```
<Image x:Name="_spinner" Source="/Test;component/_Resources/loading.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
    <SomeStyleToMakeItRotate.../>
</Image>
```

it shows correctly...

This leads me to believe that the dependency property is wrong, but how ?

### E1:

After trying to do the same steps on a different control it stopped working again.

This time I have a DP:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationFunctionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ValidationFunction), typeof(Func<string, bool>), typeof(ValidatedTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(OnAssignValidation));

public Func<string, bool> ValidationFunction {
    get => (Func<string, bool>)GetValue(ValidationFunctionProperty);
    set => SetValue(ValidationFunctionProperty, value);
}

private static void OnAssignValidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

Control usage:

```
<c:ValidatedTextBox x:Name="valid"
                    Text="Test"
                    ValidationFunction="{Binding Validation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource test}}"/>
```

The converter is just a `Debugger.Break()` and return original

And finally the `RelativeSource` control is my `MainWindow`

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
}

public Func<string,bool> Validation => (s) => true;
```

(There is a problem with the `Text` DP as well, but I think I can solve that one on my own)

### E2

Ok Pro problem was the `RelativePath` pointing to `UserControl` but it was placed in a `Window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency property declaration is wrong, because the `get`/`set` methods of the CLR property wrapper must call the `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods of the DependencyObject base class (and nothing else).

Besides that, the property should also use `ImageSource` as its type:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SpinnerSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(SpinnerSource), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(Spinner));

public ImageSource SpinnerSource
{
    get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SpinnerSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SpinnerSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

The Image element in the UserControl's XAML would use the property like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding SpinnerSource,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Comment: Oh I did not know that you can bind the dependency properties like this. Cool, now it is working.